# How to remove minicart from sticky header

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

In my project minicart comes under both header & sticky header. **But I want to remove it from sticky header**. Is there any setting from backend or which file I need to edit to hide checkout from sticky header. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are Using Custom Theme Check your header block, there should be a block named as mini_cart(block-name could be change according to your theme) , I wonder your sticky header is rending to the header block.

If you want to remove minicart from complete header you could use Magento XML to remover blocks from layouts.

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Even Magento2 Provides us the way to disable Minicart popup through
>   admin panel, To disable, go to *Stores* > *Configuration* > *Sales* >
>   *Checkout* > *Shopping Cart Sidebar* and change "Display Shopping Cart
>   Sidebar" to No.

Or Else **You want to Disable Minicart only on Sticky Header** You can do so with Css:

Checkout the class Sticky header is adding to parent class after a slight scroll, It should be .active or .opened or anything like that.

just add the css in your custom style sheet

```
.parentClass.active{
     display:none;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Glad to help :)